# How do I make screenshot of Xcode storyboard?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I need to take a screenshot of whole storyboard as an image. Is that possible? I need it to give to my designer.

Ideally I'd like to get 1 big image, make some changes (number views, etc) and save it as JPG

Comment: Apple is aware of this and my bugreport was closed as a duplicate of radar://9587920

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode doesn't have any features for printing or exporting an image of your storyboard. (Though that might make a good [feature request to send to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).)

Your best bet is to resize your project window as large as possible (and hide the navigator and utility sidebars) and take a screenshot. You might be able to employ a trick or two in getting everything to fit:

- If you're on a Mac with a Retina Display, change your screen resolution to one of the "more space" options so your Xcode window can be bigger. (For example, on a 5K iMac you can choose the "looks like 3200 x 1800" size, which renders a 6400 x 3600 screen and downscales it to fit the actual display hardware.)
- Zoom out on the storyboard with the Editor > Canvas > Zoom menu commands. In Xcode 8, the zoomed-out storyboard uses the same rendering/editing engine as the regular-size view — which means that on a Retina display, your shrunken-down views will still be legible.
- Resize the window larger than the screen, then take a window screenshot (Cmd-Shift-4, then spacebar, then click the window). You can do this with AppleScript:

  ```
  tell application "Xcode" to set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 4000, 3000}
  ```

  But that'll still limit its *height* to that of the screen (minus menubar and Dock). You can drag the window to the bottom of the screen and edge-resize it upward to get some extra height, though.

One more thing: Since the beginning of storyboards (way back in Xcode... 5, I think?), you've never needed to have "one storyboard to rule them all" in your project. In fact, there are lots of reasons why it might make sense to break your app into multiple storyboards. And of course, if you have multiple storyboards, you can screenshot them separately and integrate them however you like for a design presentation.

Using multiple storyboards used to mean you couldn't segue between view controllers in separate storyboards (you'd have to instantiate and present view controllers programmatically), but since Xcode 7 you can insert a "Storyboard Reference" in one storyboard to link to a view controller in a different storyboard. And if you have a big storyboard you want to break up, there's a tool for that. (Select some view controllers, choose Editor > Refactor to Storyboard...)

Comment: 2016 and still no feature added to XCode7.3?

Comment: 2016 and did anyone file a bug? (Maybe someone did and didn't tell the rest of us?)